# How can I approach solving this integral when it appears that u-substitution doesn't work?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\frac{\tan\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\ dx$$

I originally thought to let $u=\sqrt{x}$, but then this would mean I have $\displaystyle2\cdot \int\frac{\tan u}{u}\ du$, which is just the same type of problem.

Comment: Actually it would reduce to
$$
2\cdot\int \tan u \,{\rm d}u
$$
since ${\rm d}x=2u{\rm d}u$...

Comment: Be it as it may, multiplying and dividing by 2, without substitution you would have
$$
2\int f\big(g(x)\big)g'(x)\,{\rm d}x = 2F\big(g(x)\big)
$$
where $f(x)=\tan x$, $g(x)=\sqrt x$ and $F'=f$.

Comment: See AndreasT's comment and note $\tan u={\sin u\over \cos u}$. Time for one more substitution... (Note that an appropriate substitution at the start is all that's needed.)

Comment: @agent54 : You can't just change $dx$ to $du$.  That's the most important thing you can learn about how these substitutions work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make the substitution you will get $du=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ in other words $dx=2u\,du$ Thus the integral becomes$$\int\frac{\tan(u)}{u} 2u\,du=2\int \tan(u)\,du.$$ I think you can continue  from here.

Answer (score 5):

$$u=\sqrt{x}$$
$$du = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
$$2\,du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$$
$$\int\frac{\tan\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \int(\tan u)\big(2\,du\big)=2\int\tan u\,du$$
$$=2\int\frac{\sin u}{\cos u}\,du = 2\int \frac{1}{\cos u}\Big(-\sin u\,du\Big) = 2\int\frac1w\left(-dw\right)$$